Why does using empty value for row grouping show blank(table) report pages?
What I am trying to do is simple report that should printed from Business Central. It works perfectly expect when there is empty field value report Tablix doesn't show.
Report page with blank group value
I want the report to show like this. In this case, if the Alley Code is empty, alley code itself should be empty while other report objects are showing.
Pages with no empty group value
I am suspecting my row grouping here, but can't think of what exactly my error is.
RDLC layout grouping
Also, English is my second language. Sorry for the bad sentences.
